# Cannot install ctex via tlmgr: "Unknown option: status-file" when running fmtutil-sys

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, ctex, fmtutil, texlive-2021

I am trying to install `ctex` through `tlmgr`. However, it fails. (For other packages, it works fine, so I guess it is not a general error.)

Here is the command I run:

```bash
tlmgr update --self && tlmgr install ctex
```

(Full disclosure: I am running this in the Docker image `pandoc/ubuntu-latex:2.13`, but I guess this should not make a difference.)

The relevant section of the log:

```
regenerating fmtutil.cnf in /opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist
running fmtutil-sys --byengine ptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp ...
tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --byengine ptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp failed (status 255), output:
Unknown option: status-file
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.

running fmtutil-sys --byengine euptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp ...
tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --byengine euptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp failed (status 255), output:
Unknown option: status-file
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.
Cannot read status file /tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp, strange!

running fmtutil-sys --byengine uptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp ...
tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --byengine uptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp failed (status 255), output:
Unknown option: status-file
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.
Cannot read status file /tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp, strange!

running fmtutil-sys --byengine eptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp ...
tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --byengine eptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp failed (status 255), output:
Unknown option: status-file
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.
Cannot read status file /tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp, strange!
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

So it appears that the first error is that `fmtutil-sys` does not recognize the option `--status-file`, and then it complains that it does not find said status file.

This also seems to be specific to TeXLive 2021, as I can install ctex in TeXLive 2020.

Is there a bug in ctex? Or in TeXLive 2021? Or am I doing something wrong?

Full log below:

```
tlmgr: package repository https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /opt/texlive/texdir/tlpkg/backups
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] update: texlive.infra [226k] (58646 -> 59259) ... done
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr: package log updated: /opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: package repository https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
[1/36, ??:??/??:??] install: adobemapping [2120k]
[2/36, 00:01/00:41] install: arphic [26742k]
[3/36, 00:07/00:21] install: cjk [57k]
[4/36, 00:07/00:21] install: cjkpunct [4k]
[5/36, 00:07/00:21] install: cns [2916k]
[6/36, 00:08/00:22] install: ctex [127k]
[7/36, 00:09/00:25] install: everyhook [3k]
[8/36, 00:09/00:25] install: fandol [21077k]
[9/36, 00:14/00:23] install: fonts-tlwg [4908k]
[10/36, 00:16/00:24] install: garuda-c90 [4k]
[11/36, 00:16/00:24] install: latex-firstaid-dev [3k]
[12/36, 00:16/00:24] install: luatexja [186k]
[13/36, 00:16/00:24] install: norasi-c90 [9k]
[14/36, 00:17/00:25] install: platex.x86_64-linux [1k]
[15/36, 00:17/00:25] install: platex [41k]
[16/36, 00:17/00:25] install: platex-tools [8k]
[17/36, 00:17/00:25] install: ptex.x86_64-linux [1427k]
[18/36, 00:18/00:26] install: ptex [1k]
[19/36, 00:18/00:26] install: ptex-base [10k]
[20/36, 00:19/00:28] install: ptex-fonts [14k]
[21/36, 00:19/00:28] install: svn-prov [3k]
[22/36, 00:19/00:28] install: ttfutils.x86_64-linux [423k]
[23/36, 00:20/00:29] install: ttfutils [107k]
[24/36, 00:20/00:29] install: uhc [3516k]
[25/36, 00:21/00:29] install: uplatex.x86_64-linux [1k]
[26/36, 00:21/00:29] install: uplatex [15k]
[27/36, 00:22/00:30] install: uptex.x86_64-linux [7092k]
[28/36, 00:24/00:30] install: uptex [1k]
[29/36, 00:24/00:30] install: uptex-base [10k]
[30/36, 00:24/00:30] install: uptex-fonts [166k]
[31/36, 00:25/00:31] install: wadalab [17357k]
[32/36, 00:29/00:29] install: xcjk2uni [196k]
[33/36, 00:29/00:29] install: xpinyin [197k]
[34/36, 00:30/00:30] install: zhmetrics [59k]
[35/36, 00:30/00:30] install: zhmetrics-uptex [31k]
[36/36, 00:31/00:31] install: zhnumber [8k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
regenerating fmtutil.cnf in /opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist
running fmtutil-sys --byengine ptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp ...
tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --byengine ptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp failed (status 255), output:
Unknown option: status-file
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.

running fmtutil-sys --byengine euptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp ...
tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --byengine euptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp failed (status 255), output:
Unknown option: status-file
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.
Cannot read status file /tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp, strange!

running fmtutil-sys --byengine uptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp ...
tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --byengine uptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp failed (status 255), output:
Unknown option: status-file
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.
Cannot read status file /tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp, strange!

running fmtutil-sys --byengine eptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp ...
tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --byengine eptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp failed (status 255), output:
Unknown option: status-file
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.
Cannot read status file /tmp/nWX38sMPZe/3IT_PnVZYp, strange!
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.

tlmgr: package log updated: /opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: command log updated: /opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
```

Comment: The same happened to me to the `R` image in GitHub. I wasn't able to solve it --- I suppose is a mismatch when somebody tried to update a TexLiVe2020 to 2021. I have a 2021 locally with full installation without problem. I simply changed the image and used a standard one with a distro-provided latex (in my case I could). But I am still puzzled about what could have happened, so +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fmtutil` got this new options some time ago, you need to update the `texlive-scripts` package. `tlmgr update texlive-scripts` should do that. After that, `fmtutil` will provide the respective command line option.

Just FYI, on my system I see

```
tlmgr info texlive-scripts
package:     texlive-scripts
category:    TLCore
shortdesc:   TeX Live infrastructure programs
longdesc:    Includes install-tl, tl-portable, rungs, etc.; not needed for tlmgr to run but still ours. Not included in tlcritical.
installed:   Yes
revision:    59362
sizes:       doc: 1957k, run: 629k, bin: 53k
relocatable: No
collection:  collection-basic
```

and you should have the same `revision` number.